# boost::asio UDP "gather" operation

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

The `boost::asio` documentation for [`async_receive()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/async_receive/overload1.html) states that it supports *"receiving into multiple buffers in one go"*, and while I can code this I can't actually see how (or if) it works.

We have a situation where one of our vendors is sending us many thousands of UDP packets per second, enough that we're seeing the "Packets Received Discarded" spiking in certain situations.

It would be ideal if we really could fill multiple buffers in one `async_receive()` call, but during testing it seems that even if multiple buffers are specified, the handler is only called for one datagram.

I've included my test code, sorry it's so verbose, but I needed it to be flexible to listen on multiple interfaces/multicasts.

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>

// configuration options...
std::string nic;
std::string mc;
uint16_t port = 0;
uint16_t buffer_size = 0;
uint32_t socket_buffer_size = 0;
uint32_t scat_cnt = 1;

// The raw data buffer
std::vector<uint8_t> buffer;

// The scatter/gather buffer
std::vector<boost::asio::mutable_buffer> gather_buffer;

boost::asio::io_service svc;
std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket> socket_;

size_t messages_received = 0;
size_t bytes_received = 0;

bool parse_command_line(std::vector<std::string> command_line);

void on_receive(const boost::system::error_code& ec, size_t bytes)
{
   if(!ec)
   {
      socket_->async_receive(
         gather_buffer,
         [] (const boost::system::error_code& ec, size_t bytes)
      {
         on_receive(ec, bytes);
      });

      ++messages_received;
      bytes_received += bytes;

      if(0 == messages_received % 1000)
      {
         std::cout << "Received: " << messages_received << " messages, " << bytes_received << " bytes.\n";
      }
   }
   else
   {
      std::cout << "Error: " << ec.message() << '\n';
   }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   if(parse_command_line(std::vector<std::string>(argv, argv+argc)))
   {
      try
      {
         std::cout << "Resizing segment buffer to: " << buffer_size << std::endl;
         buffer.resize(buffer_size * scat_cnt);

         for(uint32_t x = 0; x < scat_cnt; ++x)
         {
            gather_buffer.push_back(
               boost::asio::buffer(buffer.data() + (buffer_size * x), buffer_size));
         }

         std::cout << "Setting up receiving socket." << std::endl;
         socket_.reset(new boost::asio::ip::udp::socket(svc));
         socket_->open(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4());

         socket_->set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address(true));

         std::cout << "Binding to local NIC: " << nic << std::endl;
         socket_->bind(boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(nic), port));

         boost::asio::socket_base::non_blocking_io no_block(true);
         socket_->io_control(no_block);

         std::cout << "Setting socket buffer size to " << socket_buffer_size << std::endl;
         boost::asio::socket_base::receive_buffer_size sock_bf_sz(socket_buffer_size);
         socket_->set_option(sock_bf_sz);

         std::cout << "Joining multicast " << mc << " on " << nic << std::endl;
         boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group jg(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string(mc), boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string(nic));
         socket_->set_option(jg);

         std::cout << "Listening..." << std::endl;

         socket_->async_receive(
            gather_buffer,
            [] (const boost::system::error_code& ec, size_t bytes)
         {
            on_receive(ec, bytes);
         });

         std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> w(new boost::asio::io_service::work(svc));

         std::cout << "Starting boost proactor..." << std::endl;
         boost::thread thread([&] () { svc.run(); });

         boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(60));
         w.reset();

         thread.join();
      }

      catch(boost::system::error_code& ec)
      {
         std::cout << "Boost error: " << ec.message() << '\n';
      }

      catch(...)
      {
         std::cout << "Unknown Error!\n";
      }
   }

   return 0;
}

bool parse_command_line(std::vector<std::string> command_line)
{
   for(size_t idx = 0, max_switches = command_line.size();
      idx < max_switches; ++idx)
   {
      auto& curr = command_line[idx];
      std::transform(curr.begin(), curr.end(), curr.begin(), ::tolower);

      if(curr == "-nic" && ++idx < max_switches)
      {
         nic = command_line[idx];
      }
      else if(curr == "-multicast" && ++idx < max_switches)
      {
         mc = command_line[idx];
      }
      else if(curr == "-port" && ++idx < max_switches)
      {
         port = boost::lexical_cast<uint16_t>(command_line[idx]);
      }
      else if(curr == "-bfsz" && ++idx < max_switches)
      {
         buffer_size = boost::lexical_cast<uint16_t>(command_line[idx]);
      }
      else if(curr == "-sockbfsz" && ++idx < max_switches)
      {
         socket_buffer_size = boost::lexical_cast<uint32_t>(command_line[idx]);
      }
      else if(curr == "-scattercnt" && ++idx < max_switches)
      {
         scat_cnt = boost::lexical_cast<uint32_t>(command_line[idx]);
      }
   }

   std::cout
      << "NIC:                " << nic << '\n'
      << "MC:                 " << mc << '\n'
      << "Port:               " << port << '\n'
      << "Segment Size:       " << buffer_size << '\n'
      << "Socket Buffer Size: " << socket_buffer_size << '\n'
      << "Scatter/Gather:     " << scat_cnt << std::endl;

   return 
      !nic.empty() &&
      !mc.empty() &&
      port != 0 &&
      buffer_size != 0 &&
      socket_buffer_size != 0
      ;
}
```

Comment: What do you think asio is buying you over just blocking in `recvfrom`?

Comment: `async_read_some` would do this for tcp.  I'm not sure if there's an equivalent for a udp socket.  You may be better off using a single large buffer, and copying everything available in the socket buffer (possibly increase its size) before doing any processing.  I've been able to process over 80MiB/s using this  architecture with Asio before.  Handling partial packets is non-trivial though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll receive into multiple buffers, but you're never going to get more than one datagram at a time. That's just how `recv` works and I think people would be pretty surprised if its behavior suddenly changed. The intent of gather is to split a single packet into multiple buffers, which may be useful if you're expecting to receive data that is conceptually segmented, but it is not for receiving multiple buffers. This is basically a wrapper around `recvmsg`.

Maybe try not using boost::asio?

Comment: or maybe just not udp. If losing datagrams is an issue, udp is not the right solution. By using STREAM mode sockets, the kernel can queue and buffer, and consequently you can receive the net worth of more than 1 ip packet in one call to receive. At the same time you'll have the "no-loss" guarantee (unless the sender times out waiting for the receiver to catch up).